# Discord.py Wait for user that is not the author of the command to react to a message(embed)

Tags: python, discord.py

essentially I'm trying to create a 1v1 game between the author and someone who reacts to an embed. Like if you were to play tic tac toe for example a user would initiate an invite using "!play" then the next person to react will start a match between the two.

Currently, I have tried wait_for like in the documentation however it only continues if the user that issued the "!play" command reacts, I have looked around but am a bit stuck. Here is the code as follows:

```
msg = await ctx.send(embed=invite)
await msg.add_reaction('✅')

try:
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author and reaction.emoji in [u"\u2705"], timeout=30.0)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("Nobody wanted to play with you :(")
else:
    if reaction.emoji == u"\u2705":
        await ctx.send("Starting game with: " + ctx.message.author.name + " & " + str(user))
```

The output when the author of the command reacts: Starting game with: user & user.

The output when someone else reacts: Results in timeout

I've seen some stuff with on_reaction_add however I don't want more than 1 person to react to it

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lambda check you're currently checking if `user == ctx.author` which you would simply have to change to `user != ctx.author`